# Is the surface of a sphere 2D or 3D

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, spherical-harmonics, riemann-sphere

I'm reading an [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.10130.pdf) and it describes signals on a sphere. I dont understand how SO(3) isn't considered a signal on the sphere. And why is the sphere referred to as S2, when spheres are 3D manifolds? the statement is below:

"whereas the space of moves for the plane (2D translations) is itself isomorphic to the plane, the space of moves for the sphere (3D rotations) is a different, three-dimensional manifold called SO(3). It follows that the result of a spherical correlation (the output feature map) is to be considered a signal on SO(3), not a signal on the sphere, S2."

Comment: A sphere is a 2-dimensional manifold. A point on the sphere can only move in two directions, namely: longitude and lattitude (except at the poles). In essence, it is locally euclidean. The sphere is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so thats where the 3D comes from.

Comment: There are many different kinds of dimension: small inductive, large inductive, covering, vector-space, Hilbert-space, and others.

Answer (score 3):

$S^2$ refers only to the *surface* of the (ordinary) sphere; it may typically be embedded in three-dimensional space, but that doesn't make it a three-dimensional manifold; it's two-dimensional. If you take a small section of it, it looks like a section of a plane, not a spatial object. After all, you can embed a circle (also known as $S^1$) in three-dimensional space too, but that doesn't make it a three-dimensional manifold either. It is one-dimensional.

As regards the other question: The space of translations is equivalent to the plane itself, because any point in the plane can be identified with the translation that moves the origin to that point, or, alternatively, with the translation that moves that point to the origin.

However, the space of rotations is not equivalent to (the surface of) the sphere $S^2$. Any rotation can be characterized by an axis around which the rotation is counter-clockwise—which can be identified with a point on the sphere—*and the amount of the rotation*. There are thus three degrees of freedom, whereas there are only two degrees of freedom on the sphere (say, longitude and latitude).

In addition, there is a wrinkle, in that the above characterization is a "double cover"; any rotation of $\theta$ around an axis $v$ can likewise be characterized as a rotation of $2\pi-\theta$ around the axis $-v$. With that duplication accounted for, [the space of rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group) is often called $\operatorname{SO}(3)$, which stands for the special orthogonal group of $3$-by-$3$ matrices. (Unsurprisingly, $\operatorname{SO}(2)$ represents [the rotations of the circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group).)

Comment: Thanks, I have a better understanding of the phrase. If I'm not mistaken SO(3) then is a group of all possible rotations of the sphere?

Comment: @a__ys: Yes that's right.

Comment: isn't it impossible to capture all possible rotations of the sphere?. I'm assuming in the case of convolution then SO(3) will represent the kernel? @Brian Tung

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What is a rotation of the sphere that is not an element of $\operatorname{SO}(3)$?

Comment: Yes, I mean how do we get all possible rotations of a sphere (intuitively you'll assume a sphere can be rotated in ∞ possible ways right). So how do we represent all rotations in SO(3)?

Comment: No, I meant to ask, if you think it's impossible to capture all possible rotations of the sphere, then you must think there's some rotation that isn't captured in $\operatorname{SO}(3)$. (There isn't, by the way, unless you mean something highly unusual by "rotation.") Please take a look at the link in my answer for additional details concerning the group and its representations; if you have any questions about those, you can follow up.

Comment: Got it, thanks!